# Use same UIAlertView on different places

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertview

I have a UIAlertView, alertView, that is initialized in viewDidLoad-method, like:

```
self.alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Meddelande"
                                            message:@"Do you want to continue?"
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
```

I also have a number of metods that is called by pressning different buttons:

```
- (IBAction)didPressButton1 {

    [self.alertView show];
}
```

I tought that this would show the alertView, but nothing happens. One solution is to call a metod that initialize the the alertView and show it at the same time, but I want this to work.

The property of the alertView look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView *alertView;
```

I also added the delegats in the class-extension like this:

```
@interface MyViewController () <UIAlertViewDelegate>
@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Hank

Comment: can you show me the property of alertView you have defined?

Comment: Did u add UIAlertViewDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing nothing bad. This code works. Your mistake is in how you declare your `alertView`.

Be sure you do it so

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)UIAlertView *alertView;
```

and you are connecting your `didPressButton1` method to your `UIButton`.

Answer (score 1):

In interface(.h) file

```
@interface Your_Class:NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIALertView *uv;
```

// In implementation file

```
@synthesize uv;
```

//In ViewDidLoad

```
self.uv = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Meddelande"
                                            message:@"Do you want to continue?"
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
```

// In Button Action

```
- (IBAction)didPressButton1 {

    [self.uv show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your didPressButton1 method is calling or not?
if not then please connect it in a proper way.